# Inserting a hyperlink in a TASK in Dynamics CRM 2013. Hyperlink does not render as HTML hyperlink

Tags: dynamics-crm, crm, dynamics-crm-2013

Using {Record URL(Dynamic)(Entity Name)} I have inserted it as part of system requirments into the "**Description**" of a **TASK** Activity.

```
 But the URL does not render as a HTML hyperlink.

 I have also tried using the <hyperlink> tag. But this does not work.
```

> (Important Note : I heard notice this is achievable in an Email
>   Activity with the Record URL(Dynamic)(Entity Name) attribute. But I am
>   trying to achieve this in a Task Activity.)

Sample example of code in Workflow that creates this task is the Text given below:

```
..... project record, available here: {Record URL(Dynamic)(Entity Name)}.
```

We are using CRM 2013 for this cutomization and configuration.
Can you tell me what I am doing wrong and what I need to change to achieve this feature.?

Answer (score 5):

Unlike email, the Description field of Tasks is plain text and doesn't support hyperlinks. Adding a formula to the task description will just display the formula text, not calculate it or generate a hyperlink.

If you need a link from a task to a specific record, add a custom lookup field to that entity. Another option would be to add an HTML Web Resource where you could show rich HTML with hyperlinks, but you'll need to create its content (with the link) on your own, no formula will generate the content for you.